# Hibernate many to many relation use table where data already exists in database

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

Users

> Name 
>   Email  
>   Status

Roles

> Name 
>   Roles

Organization

> Roles  
>   About   
>   Date

I created many to many relationship between "Users" and "Organization". As one user can be associated with many organization and one organization can contain many users. I used "Roles" as my join table. My worry is the Organization table is already filled with the data. How can I do CRUD operation in this case.

Comment: In the way you normally do things. What is your problem exactly , It does not matter that Organization table has data.

Comment: What CURD operation you need to perform ?